# How to convert the a UNIX timestamp to an array of UInt8 in Kotlin?

Tags: time, kotlin, byte, unix-timestamp, uint

I need to convert a UNIX timestamp to a `ByteArray` in Kotlin. The problem is, when I do that using the code below, I get a result like `C1F38E05` (hex) which is way above the current epoch time.

```
internal fun Int.toByteArray(): ByteArray {
    return byteArrayOf(
            this.ushr(24).toByte(),
            this.ushr(16).toByte(),
            this.ushr(8).toByte(),
            this.toByte()
    )
}

val timeUTC = System.currentTimeMillis().toInt().toByteArray()
```

What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a 32 bit value, you need to convert time to seconds.

```
fun Int.toByteArray() = byteArrayOf(
    this.toByte(),
    (this ushr 8).toByte(),
    (this ushr 16).toByte(),
    (this ushr 24).toByte()
)

val timeUTC = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000).toInt().toByteArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` returns a `Long` so `toByteArray` has to be implemented for `Long` like this:

```
fun Long.toByteArray(): ByteArray {                     
    val result = ByteArray(8)                           
    result[7] = (this and 0xFF).toByte()                
    result[6] = ((this ushr 8) and 0xFF).toByte()       
    result[5] = ((this ushr 16) and 0xFF).toByte()      
    result[4] = ((this ushr 24) and 0xFF).toByte()      
    result[3] = ((this ushr 32) and 0xFF).toByte()      
    result[2] = ((this ushr 40) and 0xFF).toByte()      
    result[1] = ((this ushr 48) and 0xFF).toByte()      
    result[0] = ((this ushr 56) and 0xFF).toByte()      
    return result                                       
}
```

If you need this for unsigned bytes use:

```
fun Long.toByteArray(): UByteArray {
    val result = UByteArray(8)
    result[7] = (this and 0xFF).toUByte()
    result[6] = ((this ushr 8) and 0xFF).toUByte()
    result[5] = ((this ushr 16) and 0xFF).toUByte()
    result[4] = ((this ushr 24) and 0xFF).toUByte()
    result[3] = ((this ushr 32) and 0xFF).toUByte()
    result[2] = ((this ushr 40) and 0xFF).toUByte()
    result[1] = ((this ushr 48) and 0xFF).toUByte()
    result[0] = ((this ushr 56) and 0xFF).toUByte()
    return result
}
```

This can be used like in the following example:

```
fun main() {
    val timeUTC = System.currentTimeMillis().toByteArray()    
    println(timeUTC.map { byte -> byte.toString(16).toUpperCase() }.joinToString(""))
}
```

Comment: What is the point of `and 0xFF`? Leftmost bits will be truncated anyway when casting to Byte.